# CSS and Javascript not loading in iOS webview

Tags: javascript, html, ios, webview

I am using WebView to load locally referenced HTML files into my app.  I have the folder structure:

```
-assets/
   -www/
     -css/
     -images/
     -js/
     -index.html
```

index.html uses relative paths to link to the various css, javascript and image files eg:

```
<script src="js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

Because I am using relative paths I am loading the HTML content into the WebView by using this code in ViewController.h

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"assets/www"]];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

When I run the iOS simulator the page successfully loads and displays an image from the images folder on the page.  However the CSS and Javascript files do not load.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: try running the same in safari and check error in console.

Comment: The page launches correctly in Safari with no errors

Comment: I cleaned up the Build.  Product -> Clean and the page loaded with the CSS and Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Change path to file .js and .css like this:

```
 <script src="../js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link href="../css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

Comment: The files aren't down a directory